# Can I assign "find next" and "Select and find next" to the same shortcut in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I would like to combine the "find next" and "Select and find next" functions, and assign them to the same shortcut (<kbd>F3</kbd>) in Notepad++.

Is this possible? How can I do it?

Comment: I don't think you can assign two actions with the same keyboard shortcut (as far as I know). In fact, `Select and Find Next` has a keyboard shortcut `ALT+ Left/Right`, which is way faster and once you get used to it, it is extremely handy.